# Scrapy collect data from first element and post's title

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I need Scrapy to collect data from this tag and retrieve all three parts in one piece. The output would be something like:

> Tonka double shock boys bike - $10 (Denver).

```
<span class="postingtitletext">Tonka double shock boys bike - <span class="price">$10</span><small> (Denver)</small></span>
```

Second is to collect data from first span tag. So the result would be only:

> 2016 2004 Pontiac Grand Prix gt.

```
 <p class="attrgroup"><span><b>2016 2004 Pontiac Grand Prix gt</b></span> <span>odometer: <b>164</b></span>  <span>fuel : <b>gas</b></span> <span>transmission : <b>automatic</b></span> <span>title status : <b>clean</b></span></p>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.csv -t csv
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


# item class included here
class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    attr = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://jxn.craigslist.org/search/cto?"
    ]

    BASE_URL = 'http://jxn.craigslist.org/'

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a[@class="hdrlnk"]/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = self.BASE_URL + link
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_attr)

    def parse_attr(self, response):
        match = re.search(r"(\w+)\.html", response.url)
        if match:
            item_id = match.group(1)
            url = self.BASE_URL + "reply/nos/vgm/" + item_id

            item = DmozItem()
            item["link"] = response.url
            item["title"] = "".join(response.xpath("//span[@class='postingtitletext']//text()").extract())
            item["tag"]=response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()
            return scrapy.Request(url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_contact)

    def parse_contact(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["attr"] = "".join(response.xpath("//div[@class='anonemail']//text()").extract())
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posting title, get all the text nodes from the `span` tag and join them:

```
$ scrapy shell http://denver.craigslist.org/bik/5042090428.html
In [1]: "".join(response.xpath("//span[@class='postingtitletext']//text()").extract())
Out[1]: u'Tonka double shock boys bike - $10 (Denver)'
```

Note that the "Scrapy-way" to do this would be to use an [`ItemLoader`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and the [`Join()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.Join) processor.

---

> Second is to collect data from first span tag.

Since you haven't provided an example input data, here is an educated guess:

```
response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[0]
```

Comment: @ArkanKalu well, for example, add a new `title` field and put `item["title"] = "".join(response.xpath("//span[@class='postingtitletext']//text()").extract())` into the `parse_attr` callback.

Comment: title part work perfect but item["tag"]=response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract() returns nothing. I've defined tag = Field() in items.py and in the beginning tag = scrapy.Field() of the test.py file.

Comment: i get this error in cmd: exceptions.AttributeError: 'FeedExporter' object has no attribute 'slot'

Comment: Hey @alecxe can u help me with this bug please? I am really stuck here

Comment: @ArkanKalu what is the current code you are executing? Thanks.

Comment: @ArkanKalu I think you need to join the tag parts too: `item["tag"] = " ".join(response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract())`. Works for me.

Comment: Works now for me too, but how can i collect data only from first span tag? Thanks

Comment: @ArkanKalu do you mean just like `response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[0]`?

Comment: That's it, runs great! :D I owe you a beer mate ;)